# PHP OOP - I am trying to output an array which has been loaded into a different class

Tags: php

class_1.php

```
class class_1
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/array.php';
    }
}
```

class_2.php

```
class class_2
{
    static function output_array()
    {
        return $array_NUMBERS;
    }
}
```

array.php

```
$array_NUMBERS = array('1', '2', '3');
```

page.php

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class_1.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class_2.php';

$obj = new class_1();

$numbers = class_2::output_array();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($numbers);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Aren't you supposed to use "require_once" within classes?

**Problem:** It's not outputting the array values.

Comment: What is the question/problem/error?

Comment: Please edit the post to include your error message, if any, or how your program functions differently than your expectations. We are not mind readers.

Comment: It's not outputting the array values. Just a blank page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a local variable in `class_1::__construct()`, which falls out of scope immediately and is lost forever.

Even if it weren't, variables declared inside a function are local to that function, and cannot be access from other functions. `class_2::output_array()` has no concept of the variable `$array_NUMBERS`. You need to read up on [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29).

To make this work, you'd have to make the variable a public member of `class_1`:

```
class class_1 {
    public $array_NUMBERS;
    function __construct() {
        require_once('array.php');
    }
}

class class_2 {
    public static function output_array() {
        $class1 = new class_1();
        return $class1->array_NUMBERS;
    }
}
```

**array.php:**

```
$this->array_NUMBERS = array(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: `include()` and co. are for pulling code in at a certain place, essentially what's happening in `class_1.php` is that you're ending up with the equivalent of this:

```
class class_1
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $array_NUMBERS = array('1', '2', '3');
    }
}
```

Thus, `$array_NUMBERS` is a local variable within the constructor, which is why `class_2` can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

With your `require_once` your code becomes:

```
class class_1
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $array_NUMBERS = array('1', '2', '3');
    }
}
```

So what you are doing, is assigning a variable in a function. As a result, the scope of that variable is only inside that function.

There are ugly hacks to get the variable to your other class / function, but the whole approach seems wrong (also see @Mike Lewis's answer).

A solution would be to define a variable in `class_1`, assign the array to that variable and pass the instance of that class as an argument to your `output_array` function.